# Invoking a function of an object inside a for loop - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, methods, invoke

I have an object called `foo`:

```
function Foo(){
  this.conceal = function(){ ... };
};
```

and a method called `toggleView`, which iterates through a collection of `foo` and calls `conceal()` method on each instance:

```
function toggleView(foos){
  for(a in foos){
    foos[a].conceal();
  }
}
```

and, of course, `foos[a].conceal();` returns: **conceal is not a function**

Comment: There's not enough code here to see what's wrong. If `foos` really is an array, you should use a plain `for` loop with a numeric index, or else `.forEach()`, to iterate. However, what you've got should work unless `foos` is *not* what you say it is.

Comment: The loop is visiting a property that doesn't hold an instance of `Foo`. Note that `for..in` loops aren't strictly limited to indexes. Related: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Are you sure you are using `new` to create Foo instances?

Comment: Try to invoke a function, outside a loop first, to see if there is any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Foo(){
  this.conceal = function( item ) { 
    console.log(item); // "a" "b" "c"
  };
};

function toggleView(foos) {
  var myFoo = new Foo();      // Create new instance (here or outside this fn)
  for(a in foos){
    myFoo.conceal(foos[a]);   // use your instance and pass as items arg. reference
  }
}

toggleView(["a","b","c"]);
```

Example making `toggleView` a **prototype** of `Foo`

```js
function Foo(){
  this.conceal = function( item ) { 
    console.log(item); // "a" "b" "c"
  };
}

Foo.prototype.toggleView = function(foos) {
  for(a in foos){
    this.conceal(foos[a]);        // invoke .conceal Method using `this` reference
  }
}

var myFoo = new Foo();            // Create new instance
myFoo.toggleView(["a","b","c"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should at some point call the function Foo so that the conceal becomes a "function".